# How to Vectorize This Matrix Operation?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

(I asked a similar question before but this is a different operation.)

I have 2 arrays of boolean masks and I am looking to calculate an operation on every combination of two masks.

## The slow version

```
N = 10000
M = 580
masksA = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)
masksB = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)

result = np.zeros(shape=(N,N), dtype=np.float)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        result[i,j] = np.float64(np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(masksA[i,:],masksB[j,:]))) / M
```

Comment: What is the operation itself for? There might be a way around the n^2 operations requirement.

Comment: You are right, one of them in the operation is masksA -- Edited.

Comment: Yes, it's perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the first input would be `masksA` as the question text reads - `"operation on every combination of two masks"`.

We can use `matrix-multiplication` to solve it, like so -

```
result = masksA.astype(np.float).dot(masksB.T)/M
```

Alternatively, use lower precision `np.float32` for dtype conversion for faster computations. Since, we are counting, it should be fine with lower precision.

Timings -

```
In [5]: N = 10000
   ...: M = 580
   ...: 
   ...: np.random.seed(0)
   ...: masksA = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)
   ...: masksB = np.array(np.random.randint(0,2, size=(N,M)), dtype=np.bool)

In [6]: %timeit masksA.astype(np.float).dot(masksB.T)
1.87 s ± 50.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [7]: %timeit masksA.astype(np.float32).dot(masksB.T)
1 s ± 7.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Is this fundamentally faster than the solution in my answer (fixed now)? I'd time it myself, but don't have access to a desktop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Don't know about faster, but the extending-dims based one with given N,M would blow up my system memory.